# How do I find the temperature fluctuation in a grand canonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature

I think that when particles and energy are allowed to freely leave the grand ensemble like that, there'll always be fluctuation in temperature despite the heat bath. But I only see particle and energy fluctuations, and temperature seems to always be considered at constant. So how do I find the T fluctuation, and is it necessary?
Thanks.

Comment: The temperature doesn't fluctuate in the grand canonical ensemble. Temperature is more like a parameter you put in to specify which ensemble you're working with.

Comment: But I find in here: [link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218593/temperature-of-system-in-canonical-ensemble) that T is not fixed in a canonical ensemble? Is it different in the GCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature is fixed in the grand canonical ensemble. In fact, for the three main ensembles we have:

- Microcanonical ensemble: fixed $N,V,E$
- Canonical ensemble: fixed $N,V,T$
- Grand canonical ensemble: fixed $\mu,V,T$

where $\mu$ is the [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential).